# how to pass an event object to triggerEventHandler in unit testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an event defined in the HTML file as :

```
(keyup)="onKeySearch($event)"
```

Now i am stimulating this event using triggerEventHandler as follows in my spec file:

```
 const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
  input.triggerEventHandler('keyup', {});
```

My query is that do we need to supply anyother parameter to the triggerEventHandler ,as the keyup event is calling the method with $event.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
input.triggerEventHandler('keyup', {target:{value: 'A'}});
```

Comment: ..it worked.Can you share any links as  to specify how or let me know any details.

Comment: whenever we receive any event in typescript, we access it like event.target.value. I passed same structure object above.